# Dynamic ScrollView with UITextView and UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` with a `UIScrollView` as a subview, which also has a `UITextField` and a `UITextView` as a subview.

The problem I am facing is I want the `UITextField` to scroll up when the user scrolls down.

Should I change the `UITextView` to a static height dynamic to the length of text and then change the `UIScrollView` to the height of both the `UITextView` + `UITextField`, if so how ?

Or more simply put how can I have the subviews of the `UIScrollView` to scroll dynamically ?

Comment: Can both be UITextView  ??

Comment: Do you want the `UITextField` to have a fixed height, so the text scrolls within it? Or do you want it to auto-size based on its text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `scrollview` to scroll you need to make its contents larger than the view.

Assuming the `UITextField` is above the `UITextView`, could you make the height of the `UITextView` larger than the `UIView` so you can then scroll the contents?

I have followed the [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/) for `UIScrollViews` which might be helpful.

Comment: So I add the subviews by code, and my UITextField has a height of 100, and the UITextView has a height == view.frame.height. But only the textView scrolls

Comment: Sorry im misunderstanding, Do you mean the textView content scrolls or the textView scrolls over the textField? is it possible for you to attached the code/solution?